# Error consuming web service (There was an error reflecting 'inputParamName')

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I created a C# client that consumes a third-party web service, apparently created using Java.

I add the service reference in VS2012 successfully, but when I call a method, the following exception is thrown:

> InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   'nameOfInputParameter'.

Its inner exception is:

> InvalidOperationException: The Form property may not be 'Unqualified'
>   when an explicit Namespace property is present.

Does anyone know why it happens and what I have to do to successful consume it?

Not sure if relevant, but the web service requires a certificate, which I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the WSDL generated by the service provider has some inconsistency, and not the .NET consumer.

Anyway, I managed to create a workaround by editing manually the `Reference.cs` VS generated and removing the attributes that correspond to the WSDL namespaces.

By the way, the certificate has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Hey, could you tell in details how exactly you fixed the issue? I have exactly the same problem with 3rd party SOAP webservice, the same exception is thrown.